# Django Load testing using locust giving Csrf token error

Tags: django, load-testing, locust

I am writing a script for load testing for my django application , but I am getting error as :

```
raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

Here is my script:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
import requests

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        response = self.client.get("/")
        csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken']
        self.client.post('/check_login/',{'username': '####', 'password': '########'},headers={'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken})


    @task(2)
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task(1)
    def profile(self):
        self.client.get("/home")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

In command Line ,I am giving this command to start locust : `locust --host=http://localhost:8080`

Any suggestions on how to rectify this error ?

Comment: Have you find a solution? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: In the login(), do get('/check_login/') instead of get('/')

Answer (score 4):

There are two requirements for this to work:

1. csrftoken should be passed inside the form data as csrfmiddlewaretoken.
2. Along with X-CSRFToken header, Referer header
   is also required.

The code would then look like:

```
self.client.post(
    '/check_login/',
    {
        'username': '####',
        'password': '########',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
    },
    headers={
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        'Referer': self.parent.host + '/check_login/'
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 def on_start(self):
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        # login to the application
        self.client.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password')
```

this is enough for login. no need to update csrftoken in python. 3.6.8

Comment: this worked for me .. thanks. Just you need to from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have Django 1.11 instance and the name of csrftoken is other, in my case is:

```
csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken_myproject']
```

And I have searched the csrftoken name with the [devtools](https://www.chromium.org/devtools) of [Chromium browser](https://www.chromium.org/) (for example).